# I am trying to scrape flipkart using splash, but while rendering the image is getting blank

Tags: web-scraping, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

```
function main(splash, args)
  url = args.url
  assert(splash:go(url))
  assert(splash:wait(10))
  
  input_box = assert(splash:select(".Pke_EE"))
  input_box:focus()
  input_box:send_text("new balance shoes")
  assert(splash:wait(10))
  
  input_box:send_keys("<Enter>")
  assert(splash:wait(30))
  
  return splash:png()
end
```

I am trying to scrape flipkart using splash, but while rendering the image is getting blank.
I wanted to know why the blank image is getting,
Explain anyone.
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................